# Fragment showing blank but has loaded layout

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments

I am practicing with android fragments and have started with navigation drawer activity in android. i have already created three layouts and java files for those fragments. the problem is there is no content. it just shows a blank page. i have been following a tutorial from [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/) site. I have already created a frame layout also.

my code are as follows:

Drawer.java - Navigation Drawer

```
public class Drawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_purchase);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_purchase:
            fragment = new Menu1();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_service:
            fragment = new Menu2();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_balance:
            fragment = new Menu3();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
}
```

Menu2. java - Fragment

```
public class Menu2 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_2, container, false);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SAMPLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //TITLE
    getActivity().setTitle("Menu 2");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot im not sure i understand whats the problem.